# why doesn't TextView set text work with int?

Tags: java, android, textview

why doesn't TextView set text work with int? 
I tried to set text of a textview through an int variable and when the code tries to set the app crash

```
TextView pntUno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.punteggioGiocatoreUno);
TextView pntDue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.punteggioGiocatoreDue);
int pnt1 = 0, pnt2 = 0;

private void punteggio(){
    pntUno.setText(pnt1);
    pntDue.setText(pnt2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setText(int resid)` instead of `setText(CharSequence text)`. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) to understand more.

To solve this, you can convert the `int` to `String` by using `String.valueOf()`:

```
private void punteggio(){
    pntUno.setText(String.valueOf(pnt1));
    pntDue.setText(String.valueOf(pnt2));
}
```

Comment: It looks like he declared pnt1, pnt2 in onCreate method. if so, it has to be passed into method punteggio()

Comment: TextViews also have to be properly intialized

Comment: @IndraKumarS, I assumed this is not his full code. pntUno, pntDue, pnt1 & pnt2 must be class members for this to compile and the init of the views can't be as it is in the current code as it would crash the app.